# Creating a new list Environment, how to change the length of \items

Tags: macros, lists, environments, margins

The code for the environment is bellow, For the longer lines in \list item how do I change the length of the `\item`s so that it lines up with the date?

Basically I want a kind of "margin" that is on the left side of the Dates, but only for the list \items.  I tried `\newgeometry` but it changes the entire page and makes a new page.  Any ideas?

### Class Document

```
\newenvironment{work}[3]{\WorkFont\WorkNameStyle #1 \hfill{}\normalsize\numberstyle #2
\\* \worklistfont\WorkDeatleStyle 
    \begin{list}{-}{#3 \vspace*{0.40em}}
}{
\end{list}\vspace*{1.0 em}}
```

---

### TeX Document

```
\begin{work}{Pennsylvania Governors School for the Sciences}{July 2007}{Physics TA/Counselor}
    \item{Taught concepts in relativistic physics to high school seniors}
    \item{Assisted project to build Wilberforce pendulum and documented findings}
    \item{Evaluated students’ progress throughout the program}
    \item{Encouraged intellectual thinking and social interaction between students}
\end{work}
```

It produces something that looks like...

[image: It produces a list that has a "title" and a date]

Comment: I think, this could be achieved easier with a tabular environment

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "line up with the date", it always helps if you supply a complete document that makes the image shown rather than just fragments. Also note `\item` does not take an argument so the `{}` are forming a group rather than marking the argument to item.

Comment: you could draw lines on the image in a bitmap editor to indicate which parts you want to align

Comment: All the 4 items are too short to fill the line until the right margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
\newenvironment{work}[3]{%
#1\hfill #2\\*#3
\begin{list}{-}{%
\settowidth{\rightmargin}{#2}}}{%
\end{list}}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could expand a little your answer?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina it's difficult for me. Did you try it? it just do what is needed

Comment: I'm intrigued by this, but do you need to set a value for the \rightmargin ?

I will try later today.

Comment: So this totally does what he says it does... and its simple but I honestly don't understand why it works.  While i'm sure the solution by "SoundsOfSilence" is more robust, or "better" in some way i'm having trouble integrating it and it requires more packages which i'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick-and-dirty `tabularx` approach, with automatic `-` at the first column. The widths of the columns etc. are just guesses, as well as the font commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\WorkFont}{\bfseries}
\newcommand{\WorkNameStyle}{\upshape}
\newcommand{\numberstyle}{\scshape}
\newcommand{\worklistfont}{\itshape}
\newcommand{\WorkDeatleStyle}{}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{-\arraybackslash}r}
\newcolumntype{I}[1]{>{\worklistfont\WorkDeatleStyle}p{#1}}

\newenvironment{work}[3]{%
  \tabularx{\linewidth}{RI{0.7\textwidth}X}
    \multicolumn{2}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\WorkFont\WorkNameStyle #1} & \numberstyle #2 \tabularnewline
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{} \tabularnewline % Empty
  }{%
  \endtabularx%
}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{work}{Pennsylvania Governors School for the Sciences}{July 2007}{Physics TA/Counselor}
& Taught concepts in relativistic physics to high school seniors  \tabularnewline
&Assisted project to build Wilberforce pendulum and documented findings \tabularnewline
&Evaluated students’ progress throughout the program \tabularnewline
&Encouraged intellectual thinking and social interaction between students \tabularnewline
\end{work}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the spacing and hyphenation are unpleasant.  a ragged right approach would improve the appearance; probably `ragged2e` would be better here than the default `\raggedright`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use a customized list defined with the help of [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and some `\parbox`es to include the information for every work:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand\WorkFont{\bfseries\raggedright}
\newcommand\WorkNameStyle{\upshape}
\newcommand\numberstyle{\scshape}
\newcommand\worklistfont{\itshape}
\newcommand\WorkDeatleStyle{}

\newlength\LongestDate

\newlist{Work}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[Work,1]{
  leftmargin=1cm,
  before=\setlength\rightmargin{\dimexpr\LongestDate+1em\relax},
  label={--}
}

\newenvironment{work}[3]
  {%
    \par\noindent
    \settowidth\LongestDate{\normalsize\numberstyle#2~}%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\LongestDate-1em\relax}{%
      {\WorkFont\WorkNameStyle\raggedright #1}\par
      {\worklistfont\WorkDeatleStyle#3}
    }%
    \hfill
    \parbox[t]{\LongestDate}{%
      {\normalsize\numberstyle #2}%
    }  
    \par\nobreak
    \begin{Work}\raggedright
  }
  {\end{Work}\vspace{1.0 em}}

\begin{document}

\begin{work}{Pennsylvania Governors School for the Sciences and some more text}{July 2007}{Physics TA/Counselor}
    \item Taught concepts in relativistic physics to high school seniors
    \item Assisted project to build Wilberforce pendulum and documented findings
    \item Evaluated students' progress throughout the program
    \item Encouraged intellectual thinking and social interaction between students
\end{work}

\begin{work}{Pennsylvania Governors School for the Sciences and some more text}{October 2015}{Physics TA/Counselor}
    \item Taught concepts in relativistic physics to high school seniors
    \item Assisted project to build Wilberforce pendulum and documented findings
    \item Evaluated students' progress throughout the program
    \item Encouraged intellectual thinking and social interaction between students
\end{work}

\end{document}
```

[image]